# Using reverse proxy to configure IIS hosted WCF services with SSL(https)

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, ssl, iis-7

I have some WCF service hosted in IIS. Client (silverlight application) is consuming the service over http. Now I want to configure that service with https/SSL.

I can see there are multiple options for that.

1. This is the standard way.
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556232(v=vs.110).aspx
2. Using reverse proxy (URL rewrite)
   http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis
   My client would send the request over https & reverse proxy server (IIS) would change/route https service request to http.

Please note my silverlight client only consumes the WCF service. There is no other client which is using that WCF service.

Can anybody tell me what is the recommenced way? What would be the advantage/disadvantage of using reverse proxy to configure WCF service with SSL?

Atul

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use URL rewrite(reverse proxy) to enable https but it is not exactly meant for that. It is mainly used to explore some internal URL to external world

You should use the standard approach (mention in #1) to enable SSL.

Annu